# XSLT 1.0 Grouping of parent node grouped by multiple child nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm trying to group based on multiple child nodes and then display the parent nodes grouped by the child nodes. I've shrunk down the examples a bit, but I hope you get the idea. Now I've got this working in XSL 2.0, but found out I can only use 1.0 in this application. I've been reading up on the Muenchian grouping method but can't seem to figure it out.

This is (part of) the XML:

```
<Persons>
    <Person PersonID="3987">
        <Desks>
            <Desk Name="10" Active="true">
            </Desk>
            <Desk Name="11" Active="true">
            </Desk>
        </Desks>
    </Person>
    <Person PersonID="3883">
        <Desks>
            <Desk Name="10" Active="true">
            </Desk>
            <Desk Name="11" Active="true">
            </Desk>
            <Desk Name="12" Active="true">
            </Desk>
            <Desk Name="13" Active="true">
            </Desk>
        </Desks>
    </Person>
</Persons>
```

This is how far I got on the Muenchian grouping method:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:key name="persons-per-desk" match="Person" use="Desks/Desk/@Name"/>

    <xsl:template match="Person[generate-id() = generate-id(key('persons-per-desk', Desks/Desk/@Name)[1])]">
        <Desk>
            <xsl:copy-of select="Desks/Desk/@Name" />
            <Person>
                <xsl:copy-of select="key('persons-per-desk', Desks/Desk/@Name)/@PersonID" />
            </Person>
        </Desk>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Person" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

What I hope to expect:

```
<Desk Name="10">
   <Person PersonID="3883"/>
   <Person PersonID="3987"/>
</Desk>
<Desk Name="11">
   <Person PersonID="3883"/>
   <Person PersonID="3987"/>
</Desk>
<Desk Name="12">
   <Person PersonID="3883"/>
</Desk>
<Desk Name="13">
   <Person PersonID="3883"/>
</Desk>
```

What I get:

```
<Desk Name="11">
   <Person PersonID="3883"/>
</Desk>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to group persons by their desk name/s - but what you need to do is group desks by their name first, then list the persons having a desk in each group:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="desk-by-name" match="Desk" use="@Name"/>

<xsl:template match="/Persons">
    <Desks>
        <!-- create a grpup for each distinct desk name -->
        <xsl:for-each select="Person/Desks/Desk[generate-id() = generate-id(key('desk-by-name', @Name)[1])]">
            <Desk Name="{@Name}">
                <!-- list the persons having desks in this group -->
                <xsl:for-each select="key('desk-by-name', @Name)/ancestor::Person">
                    <Person PersonID="{@PersonID}"/>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </Desk>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Desks>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Kind of an additional question. I would like to now add a filter to this. For example only show desks with PersonID="3987". I have just used an ´if´ statement, but this only works if my first person is PersonID="3987". If not, it will come up blank. I think this is because the XSLT has ´found´ desk 10 and 11, but didn´t list hem because of the initial filter. @michael.hor257k

Comment: Add a predicate to both the key and the for-each. If you cannot make it work, post a new question.